# HTML Canvas imageData array all 0's

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixel

```
    var img, imageData,width,height; 
    var c = canvasEle.getContext("2d");
    width = canvasEle.width;
    height = canvasEle.height;

    img = document.getElementById("id");
    c.drawImage(img,0,0);
    imageData = c.createImageData(width, height);
```

After I draw the image onto the context, then create an imageData array, the values of the array are all 0.

I have been struggling with this for hours and couldn't find any solution. The image is shown on the canvas after I draw it, but the imageData of the context says all the pixels are white. This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: What is the URL of the `<img>` element, and in particular is the domain different than your page's domain?  If so, you can't get the image data.

Comment: I'm making a user script in grease monkey. The url of the image is in the webpage I am making the user script for. So unless I'm wrong, it's in the same domain.

Comment: If it's from Greasemonkey then cross-domain issues probably don't matter.

Answer (score 3):

With `createImageData` you are creating new image data for an empty image. Please use `getImageData` to get the image data from an already existing canvas

Comment: createImageData gave me this security error: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Comment: You might have to use unsafeWindow when referring to the canvas. Otherwise there might still be issues with the same origin policy

Comment: Can I use createImageData and then put the data from the image onto it somehow? I can't seem to get past the getImageData security issue...

Comment: About 3 years ago I was able to create a userscript that created a canvas and draw on-page images to the canvas and then use the ImageData from it. But I had to use `unsafeWindow.document` whenever I was referring to the canvas (in order to create the canvas and to access it after I inserted it into the current page)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how unsafeWindow is suppose to work with getImageData? I don't understand how it works. When I tried using it, it said unsafeWindow is undefined.

Comment: Ok I checked with the current version of Greasemonkey. It is possible to create a new canvas on the page and draw an image from the same page to the canvas. It will allow you to manipulate the ImageData without any problems. So either the URL of the image is on another domain or there is some other problem. Can you show your entire userscript and the HTML of the page (at least the `img` part)?